# hadoop pig percentage within each sub-group

Tags: hadoop, apache-pig, percentage

I have a file as below

name score  
john aa  
john aa  
john aa  
john bb

mary cc  
mary cc  
mary dd

I would like to output their score percentage by number of scores for each person
so it will look like this

john aa 75  
john bb 25  
mary cc 66.6  
mary dd 33.3

John has 3 aa and 1 bb, so aa%=75 and bb%=25
I want to do it in Hadoop pig, Please help, thanks

-Troy

Comment: Thanks for posting - could you use the edit tools to today up your code a little? Thanks.

Comment: Also can you please provide more information regarding your problem. Problem statement is not clear.

Comment: basically for each name ( john,mary) produces the percentage of  by numbers of score. example : john have 3 aa and one bb then it is 75% for aa and 23% for bb. Hope this is clear, thanks also on the side note how many UDF can one pig program have ? if more than one, then what's the syntax .. REGISTER .... thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try this ?

Input: file.dat

```
john aa
john aa
john aa
john bb
mary cc
mary cc
mary dd
```

Code:

```
A = LOAD 'file.dat' USING PigStorage(' ') as (name:chararray,score:chararray);
N = CUBE A BY CUBE(name,score);      
N2 = FOREACH N GENERATE FLATTEN(group) AS (name,score), ((float)COUNT_STAR(cube)) As (totcnt:float); 
N3 = FILTER N2 BY name!='null';
N4 = GROUP N3 BY name; 
N5 = FOREACH N4 {                                                                        
 fil = order N3 BY score;                                                                 
 fil1 = LIMIT fil 1;                                                                      
 fil2 = FILTER N3 BY score!='null';                                                       
 generate FLATTEN(fil2) AS (name:chararray,score:chararray,indcount:float),FLATTEN(fil1.totcnt) as (totcnt:float);
 }
N6 = FOREACH N5 GENERATE name,score,(indcount/totcnt)*100;
DUMP N6;
```

Output:

```
(john,aa,75.0)
(john,bb,25.0)
(mary,cc,66.66667)
(mary,dd,33.333336)
```

Comment: Wow !!  The mighty CUBE works , thank YOU ! Vignesh.